# How to make business objects serialization ignorance?

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization

I have the following business object

```
public class Employee
{
   [JsonProperty("first_name")]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string Lastname { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
   public uint Salary { get; set; }
}
```

And i have the following interface and implementation for json serialization

```
 interface IJSONSerializer<T>
 {
   string Serialize(T obj);
 }

  class NewtonJsonSerialization<T> : IJSONSerializer<T>
 {
   public string Serialize(T obj)
   {
     return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
   }
 }
```

And here is my client code

```
 var Employee = new Employee();
  Employee.FirstName = "Ihor";
  Employee.Lastname = "fff";
  IJSONSerializer<Employee> serailizer = new NewtonJsonSerialization<Employee>();
  var result = serailizer.Serialize(Employee);
```

What i dislike here  - that Employee knows that it will be serialized with some specific library(because of **JsonProperty** attribute). So, if i decide to use another json  serializer or write my own, i will need to go through all business objects and modify them. Is it possible to make my business objects serialization ignorance ? If yes how ? 
The same with XML serialization and [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class: i need to mark properties in business object with some attribute.

There is a term "persistence ignorance" which means that business objects are not aware of persistence. Is there the same about serialization ?

Comment: Make properties private.

Answer (score 2):

Most serializers make use of .Net's DataContract attributes. Json.net does as well. [Try this sample out](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm) and make sure to look up [the documentation for DataMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN to learn how to influence serialization.

Comment: Let's imagine i will use DataContract attributes. If somewhen i will write my own json serializer or use, for example, JavaScriptSerializer i  still will need to go through all business objects and delete unnecessary attribute.

Comment: Sure, maybe. However, does that problem exist? I'd ask that you take a step back and ask if solving that problem today will help you deliver value to your stakeholders. If you can be reasonably sure that you won't have to support serializer "X" in the time you meet your deliverable date, I'd say move on from this problem. We software developers are smart, but even we can't predict the future. ;-)

Comment: Ah, and if you do end up writing your own serializer, make sure to support DataContract, for my and everyone else who used DataContract's sake!

Comment: Actually it's a little theoretical question ... And at the moment this problem doesn't exist. I am pretty sure that we will not change current json serializer. But by nature i am quite curious and i asked myself "what if we will change it ..." . And i understood that it will not be as quick and trivial as i would like :). So i asked this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need serialized key/element names to different than defined on your C# class, you should not worry about attributes at all. Both JSON and XML work just fine without decorating you class properties with serialization specific attributes.

If you really need custom key/element names in serialized data, then you must decorate your class props with multiple attributes. Any serializer will just read relevant attribute and ignore rest.

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    [XmlElement("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Calling Code

```
ISerializer<Person> serializer;
string result;

var person = new Person { FirstName = "Nikhil" };

serializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer<Person>();
result = serializer.Serialize(person);
/*  Output 
    {"first_name":"Nikhil"}
*/

serializer = new BuiltInXmlSerializer<Person>();
result = serializer.Serialize(person);
/*  Output
    <Person 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <first_name>Nikhil</first_name>
    </Person>
*/
```

**Edit**:

As per @Michael Nero `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes will work in most cases but not all. Very first exception on such list is .NET's built in  `XmlSerializer` which does not work without `XmlElement` attribute for custom element name.

Comment: So, if i decide to use another json serializer or write my own, i will need to go through all business objects and modify them. Is it possible to make my business objects serialization ignorance ?

Comment: See my Edit above. Forget others, if you want to work with XML then you have to modify it anyway for having custom element names. If you are fine with keys/elements to have same name as class props then you don't have to do any changes or use attributes in your class. Your choice.